# Akka http. Как включить ресурсы в страницу(css, js, картинки)?

Tags: css, scala, akka-http

В рамках учебной задачи делаю простенькую страничку(дописывая хэллоуворд пример из мануалов `akka http`). Не могу понять как подключить стили:

```
object WebServer extends App {
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system")
    implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val route =
        pathSingleSlash {
            get {
                complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
                    Layout.template(Person.list))) //Просто берет компонент Person.list и возвращает html строку
            }
        }

    Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
}
```

В шаблоне подложки(Layout) есть строка `<link href="/web/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`, которая(по моей задумке) каким-то образом должна брать файлик со стилями из ресурсов
[image: Ресурсы]

Нашел [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179581/akka-http-load-cssjs-resources) вопрос. По первому ответу у меня падает компиляция на `TemporaryRedirect`,а по второму не понимаю, куда вкорячить эту строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве решения, прописал роутинг на ресурс явным образом:

```
val route: Route =
    get {
        path("css" / "styles.css") {
            getFromResource("web/css/styles.css")
        } ~ pathSingleSlash {
            complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
                Layout.template(Person.list)))
        }
    }
```